iOS date picker flicker, when select date from datePicker in SwiftUI
I have presented datePicker in FullScreen Cover. When I select date from datePicker, it flicker or its height get increase for the first time selection.
I have tried adding frame to datePicker.
I have tried adding the date on .onAppear()
I want if user select the date , datePicker height should not increase.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Hola"
    @State var date = Date()
    @State private var check: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Select Date") {
                check.toggle()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $check, onDismiss: {
                // Update the text when the full-screen cover is dismissed
                text = formattedDate(date: date)
            }) {
                DatePickerView(date: $date)
            }
            
            Text(text)
                .padding()
        }
    }
    
    func formattedDate(date: Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}

struct DatePickerView: View {
    @Binding var date: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: Date()...Date.tomorrow, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .labelsHidden()
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)  // Prevent dynamic resizing
                .frame(width: 300, height: 400)  // Fixed size
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .onAppear {
                    date = $date.wrappedValue
                }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}

extension Date {
    static var tomorrow: Date { return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 4, to: Date())! }
}


This is likely a SwiftUI bug. I see that you attempted to change the date programmatically to cause an update to the date picker before the user sees it, using date = $date.wrappedValue. You can indeed go in this direction, but you need to set date to a different value, wait for SwiftUI to trigger a view update, and then set it back to the original value.
I'd do:
.task {
    date.addTimeInterval(1)
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1)
    date.addTimeInterval(-1)
}


It's also not hard to wrap your own UIDatePicker in a UIViewRepresentable.
struct MyDatePicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var cal
    @Environment(\.timeZone) var tz
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    
    @Binding var date: Date
    let minDate: Date
    let maxDate: Date
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        // you don't technically need to set these
        // this is just to make it work better with SwiftUI's environment
        datePicker.calendar = cal
        datePicker.timeZone = tz
        datePicker.locale = locale

        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.didSelectDate(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        uiView.minimumDate = minDate
        uiView.maximumDate = maxDate
        uiView.date = date
        context.coordinator.dateChanged = {
            date = $0
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        .init()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    @objc
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var dateChanged: ((Date) -> Void)?
        
        @objc func didSelectDate(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
            dateChanged?(datePicker.date)
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        MyDatePicker(date: $date, minDate: Date(), maxDate: Date.tomorrow)

            // frame of the UIDatePicker:
            .frame(width: 280, height: 350)

            // frame of the white background
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)

            .background(Color.white)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .shadow(radius: 10)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
}


For completeness, a third way is to use SwiftUI-Introspect to call invalidateInstrinsicContentSize on the underlying UIDatePicker, but this only works on iOS versions that you explicitly specify, so not very future-proof.
.introspect(.datePicker, on: .iOS(.v13, .v14, .v15, .v16, .v17, .v18)) { datePicker in
    datePicker.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}


Not worked after adding the time, it still flickers

@NehaPant I cannot reproduce that on iOS 17.4. Does calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize work?

@NehaPant I found that wrapping your own UIDatePicker also doesn't exhibit this behaviour. I have updated the answer.
